# Lodash isUndefined and isNull

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

Lodash offers two cool methods, `isUndefined` and `isNull`. Let's say you have a number variable that you need to check if it is set in order to use it. You could do it like this:

```
someNumber:number;
......

if (_.isUndefined(someNumber) || _.isNull(someNumber)) {
    console.log('not set');
}
```

That works alright, but what I am wondering is if there is any difference in the way it was done in the first example and if it is done like this

```
if (!someNumber) {
    console.log('not set');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0` and `NaN` pass the first test and fail the second test.

And, unimportantly, it should be `if (!someNumber)` for the "not set" case

Fun fact: `typeof NaN` is still number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In your case if the `someNumber` is `0` then the if the condition fails. But the `isUndefined` and `isNull` will pass if the value is 0